# want to keep running my single ruby crawler that dont need html and nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-crawler

first of all, I'm a newbie.

I just made a single ruby file, which crawls something on the certain web and put data into my google spreadsheet.

But I want my crawler to do its job every morning 9:00 AM. Then what do I need? Maybe a gem and server? Please let me know as detail as a beginner got understood enough...

I have tested my file on local (OS X) so far and have no server. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your computer is going to be on everyday at 9am, you could schedule it using cron.

If your computer is not going to be on everyday at 9am, you can simply buy a cheap VPS server from digitalocean, linode or one of the many other VPS hosting providers and setup a cron job there just like you did with your local computer.

The cron job would look like this:

```
0 0 9 1/1 * ? * ruby /path/to/my/ruby/file.rb
```

You can read more about setting up cron jobs here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/2368/how-do-i-set-up-a-cron-job

Comment: Thanks Jimmy! my computer is not going to be on everyday, so seems like i have to buy a server. But where do i put the cron code like you wrote above?

Comment: Once you have your server up and running, ensure that you have ruby and the gems you need to run your code installed then to add the cron job do: crontab -e which will bring up vim and allow you to edit your crontab.

Comment: hey @jimmy I posted [a new question about cron job with google api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433380/authorization-issue-with-cron-crawler-inserting-data-into-google-spreadsheet-usi) please help me if you could. Thanks!